# Retain all permissions and tasks after changing active directory

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory

We have SharePoint 2013 with AD domain like testdm. We have 2 separate Active Directory with same domain e.g. testdm.

Now we need to change our SharePoint AD with another AD that having same domain.

Currently the user is like `testdm\fname.lname` and another AD having user like `testdm\fname` for some users and same for rest users.

Every user having lots of tasks in different SharePoint list assigned in People and Group field.

We already done user migration before a year from FBA to AD by writing script.

I googled for user migration and found move-spuser powershell command but I am not sure whether I am on right direction or not.

Is it possible to maintain all users permissions and tasks as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Move-SPUser` will translate all identities for a user across the entire farm, and would be the appropriate method to use.

`$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "i:0#.w|testdm\fname.lname" -Web http://siteCollectionUrl
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "testdm\fname" -IgnoreSid`

I'm making the assumption you are using Windows Claims, hence the `i:0#.w|` format to the username in `Get-SPUser` (using the format in `Move-SPUser` isn't valid). The `-Web` parameter requires a `Site Collection` URL where the user to be migrated has an entry.

I'd suggest running this as the Farm Administrator, or a user with Full Control over the `User Profile Service Application`.

Comment: Thanks Trevor Seward. One more question: We have restored SharePoint site backup into a new server where our second AD is connected. Will $user = Get-SPUser -Identity "i:0#.w|testdm\fname.lname" -Web http://siteCollectionUrl work with old user there?

Comment: As long as the user exists within the Site Collection, it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Trevor Seward. Yes Get-SPUser is working perfect. I am going to perform actual scenario probably in next week. I'll mark your answer as accepted once perform actual test. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Trevor Seward. We are going for final user migration. Can you please tell me, Does it affect anything to New AD users if something goes wrong while processing? I just want to make sure it will not affect to any AD users because New AD is also used for our live exchange accounts.

Comment: It doesn't impact users you're not migrating.

Comment: Let me explain more in detail

Comment: E.g. We have one user named "fname.lname" in site collection which was in previous AD. We have same user named "fname" in new AD. Now I execute move -spuser command 

$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "i:0#.w|testdm\fname.lname" -Web http://siteCollectionUrl
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "testdm\fname" -IgnoreSid

So my question is: Does it affect AD user inside AD named "fname" suppose anything goes wrong.

Comment: The user isn't based just upon the username, so there is no conflict there. I suggest you just try it.

Comment: Hi Trevor Seward, It worked :)